# Transformation of State Space model

Tags: matlab, controls, mathematical-optimization

I have a state space model with 23 states, 5 inputs and 9 outputs. So the matrices A,B,C and D are known.
I am looking for a way to calculate the state space model for a different set of inputs and outputs, by transforming the initial matrices A,B,C and D?

Example: Let's say that the initial system is:
X' = A.X + B.U with `U = [u1 ; u2 ; u3 ; u4 ; u5]` and `X` is the state vector.
Y = C.X + D.U with `Y = [y1 ; y2 ; y3 ; y4 ; y5 ; y6 ; y7 ; y8 ; y9]`
and A, B, C and D are known.

How can I transform this model into a new model with another set of inputs and outputs like:

```
U_new = [y1 ; y2 ; y3 ; y4 ; y5]
Y_new = [y6 ; y7 ; y8 ; y9]
```

which are basically two subsets of the original output vector `Y`.

Is it possible without transforming the State Space Model into Transfer Functions?

I appreciate your help.
Best regards. A1ireza

Comment: What do you mean by "transform"? Are your new inputs a linear combination of the original inputs? When you say that your inputs are a subset of the original outputs, are you applying a feedback?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.